# I want to use Javascript to get specific text from a website? .getElementbyId

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to Scarpe the number of problems I have solved across all the coding platforms.
The approach I went for is to go to the profile URL of each of these platforms and then, get the number of problems solved displayed there.

For leetcode it is defined by the class name below, and I have check it works using console.

Now the problem is, I have no idea how to use this document.getElementByClassName on an external website.

```
    var url='https://leetcode.com/profileID/';
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("text-[24px] font-medium text-label-1 dark:text-dark-label-1")[0].innerText;
    console.log(elements);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try and it worked

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("text-[24px] font-medium text-label-1 dark:text-dark-label-1")[0].textContent.trim();
```

Comment: That works too, but the problem is I want to scarpe this data without opening the website